# MySQL/SQL - When are the results of a sub-query avaliable?

Tags: sql, mysql

Suppose I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT * FROM table_a   
   WHERE id > 10 )
  AS a_results LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT * from table_b
      WHERE id IN 
       (SElECT id FROM a_results)

  ON (a_results.id = b_results.id)
```

I would get the error "a_results is not a table". Anywhere I could use the re-use the results of the subquery?

Edit: It has been noted that this query doesn't make sense...it doesn't, yes. This is just to illustrate the question which I am asking; the 'real' query actually looks something like this:

```
      SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM
            (  SELECT wp_pod_tbl_hotel . *
            FROM wp_pod_tbl_hotel, wp_pod_rel, wp_pod
            WHERE wp_pod_rel.field_id =12
            AND wp_pod_rel.tbl_row_id =1
            AND wp_pod.tbl_row_id = wp_pod_tbl_hotel.id
            AND wp_pod_rel.pod_id = wp_pod.id
        )  as
              found_hotel LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT COUNT(*) as review_count, avg( (
                    location_rating + staff_performance_rating + condition_rating + room_comfort_rating + food_rating + value_rating
                                        ) /6 ) AS average_score, hotelid
                                        FROM (

                                            SELECT r. * , wp_pod_rel.tbl_row_id AS hotelid
                                                FROM wp_pod_tbl_review r, wp_pod_rel, wp_pod
                                                WHERE wp_pod_rel.field_id =11
                                                AND wp_pod_rel.pod_id = wp_pod.id
                                                AND r.id = wp_pod.tbl_row_id
                                                AND wp_pod_rel.tbl_row_id
                                                IN (                                                

SELECT wp_pod_tbl_hotel .id
            FROM wp_pod_tbl_hotel, wp_pod_rel, wp_pod
            WHERE wp_pod_rel.field_id =12
            AND wp_pod_rel.tbl_row_id =1
            AND wp_pod.tbl_row_id = wp_pod_tbl_hotel.id
            AND wp_pod_rel.pod_id = wp_pod.id

                                                    )
      ) AS hotel_reviews
           GROUP BY hotel_reviews.hotelid
          ORDER BY average_score DESC
                 AS sorted_hotel ON (id = sorted_hotel.hotelid)
```

As you can see, the sub-query which makes up the found_query table is repeated elsewhere downward as another sub-query, so I was hoping to re-use the results

Comment: The SQL above seems a bit complicated - what are you trying to do - get all results from a that outer join with b, where a.id > 10?  

If so, why not SELECT * FROM table_a LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id WHERE table_a.id > 10

Or have I misunderstood your intent?

Comment: The real query is a lot more complicated than this, which is why I come up with a mock one just to illustrate the problem

Comment: Haven't had chance to review your SQL above yet, but one thought is whether you can use a temporary table to help store the results that you then intend to reuse?

Comment: You might want to reformat that code. Also, you open more parentheses than you close...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use a sub-query like this.

I'm not sure I understand your query, but wouldn't that be sufficient?

```
SELECT * FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON ( b.id = a.id )
WHERE a.id > 10
```

It would return all rows from `table_a` where `id > 10` and `LEFT JOIN` rows from `table_b` where `id` matches.